# How can I fill a dynamic range with formulas in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, formula

I use the following code in VBA to fill a column upto a certain cell of choice (which can be changed by changing cell value) with a formula:

```
Worksheets("Deelnemersbestand").Range("B2:B"&aantalDeelnemers).Formula="=RAND()"
```

I wish to clear the rest of that column B as well.

But it does not work. Any suggestions? I am new to this.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"? What happens instead, and what's the value of `aantalDeelnemers`?

Comment: I get an error: 
Run-time error ' 1004'  
Application-defined or object-defined error
I've set the value of aantalDeelnemers to 10

Comment: You've probably just mistyped *Deelnemersbestand* or *aantalDeelnemers*. Possibly operating under the wrong active workbook. What happens when you change `"B2:B"&aantalDeelnemers` to `"B2:B" & aantalDeelnemers` and `.Formula="=RAND()"` to `.Formula = "=RAND()"`?

Comment: The spacing does not seem to matter. I have no typo's either..so frustrating

Comment: what is your complete code? How are you clearing the rest of column B and what is to be cleared and to be kept exactly? I also suggest to use option explicit and declare your variables correctly

Comment: That part works now, my mistake was in declaring "aantalDeelnemers". Clearing the rest of the column I find difficult. If you can help with this? The code is as follows:    Dim aantalDeelnemers As Integers
    aantalDeelnemers = Worksheets("Interface").Range("aantalDeelnemers").Value
    aantalDeelnemersLegen=aantalDeelnemers+1    
Worksheets("Deelnemersbestand").Range("B2:B" & aantalDeelnemers).Formula = "=RAND()" 
    Worksheets("Deelnemersbestand").Range("B"& aantalDeelnemersLegen:"B1000").ClearContents
So I fill my column upto aantalDeelnemers and from that point on clear the column

Comment: Check thoroughly spelling of sheet's name and variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

Dim aantalDeelnemers, aantalDeelnemersLegen As Integer


aantalDeelnemers = Worksheets("Interface").Range("aantalDeelnemers").Value
aantalDeelnemersLegen = aantalDeelnemers + 1
Worksheets("Deelnemersbestand").Range("B2:B" & aantalDeelnemers).Formula = "=RAND()"
Worksheets("Deelnemersbestand").Range("B" & aantalDeelnemersLegen & 
":B1000").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Do you perhaps know why Worksheets("Deelnemersbestand").Range("B2:B" & aantalDeelnemers).Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(21;50)" does not work?
Here I only changed RAND() to RANDBETWEEN(21;50)

Comment: @tam,`.Formula` expects the US comma not a semi-colon. Use a comma or use `.FormulaLocal` if you want to use a semi-colon.

Comment: In the above Dim statement, aantalDeelnemers is a variant. Use `Dim aantalDeelnemers As Integer, aantalDeelnemersLegen As Integer` if you want both as Integer type vars. (to @Tam, note Integer and not Integer**s**).

Answer (score 0):

## RAND vs RANDBETWEEN

To enable `RANDBETWEEN`, in Excel you have to go to Tools>Add-ins and check Analysis ToolPak.

```
Sub Bestand()

  Const cWs1 As String = "Interface"            ' First Worksheet
  Const cWs2 As String = "Deelnemersbestand"    ' Second Worksheet
  Const cRngName As String = "aantalDeelnemers" ' Cell Range in First Worksheet
  Const cColumn As Variant = "B"                ' Column Letter/Number
  Const cFirstRow As Integer = 2                ' First Row of Data
  Const cFormula As String = "=RAND()" '"=RANDBETWEEN(21,50)"

  Dim i As Integer

  i = Worksheets(cWs1).Range(cRngName).Value

  With Worksheets(cWs2)
    .Range(.Cells(cFirstRow, cColumn), .Cells(i, cColumn)).Formula = cFormula
    .Range(.Cells(i + 1, cColumn), .Cells(.Rows.Count, cColumn)).ClearContents
  End With

End Sub
```